# Laravel не сохраняет в базу

Tags: php, laravel

Всё как в документации

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{

    $sponsor = new Sponsor;

    if ($sponsor->validate($request->all())) {
        $sponsor->name = $request->name;
        $sponsor->text = $request->text;
        $sponsor->logo = $request->logo;

            //TODO: Upload logo

        $sponsor->save();

        return $sponsor;
    } else {
        return ['errors' => $sponsor->errors()];
    }
}
```

Проверял что приходит в $request - данные есть, и в объект $sponsor они добавляются, но в базу не сохраняется.

Answer (score -1):

Пересмотрите момент валидации данных:

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
]);
```

> The validate method accepts an incoming HTTP request and a set of validation rules. If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user.

Более подробно в документации: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation